# trying to install atom text editor

Tags: software-installation, atom

I used the following command after finding it on a thread:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite atom-amd64.deb
 (Reading database ... 256705 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack atom-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking atom (1.19.1) over (1.19.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of atom:
 atom depends on git; however:
  Package git is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package atom (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+17.04.20170406-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 atom
```

I am able to open and use atom. No problems yet. But should I  do anything about the  error message?

Comment: How can you say that it is working given that most Atom functionality relies on having git?

Comment: well it started well enough.... i didn't work on it much and yes i did get a warning box that dependencies are missing but the problem got solved after using: sudo apt-get -f install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing packages with options like `--force` is not a good idea because even if there is a problem you force the package manager to install it anyway . As you may know the package manager (`dpkg`) has a database and a messed up installation can cause inconsistencies in the database.

As an example you install package `xxx10.deb` therefore package manager won't let you install `xxx9.deb` but you *can* install it with `--force` option . Now when you are going to remove `xxx` package manager finds an ambiguity.

I prefer to use apt. You can usually resolve dependency issues with the command

```
 sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Glad to hear . Your welcome

Comment: I don't think this is quite correct, although I may certainly be wrong. Even using `--force` won't create database inconsistencies since dpkg knows what you forced it to do. The problem is that `--force` options allow sets of incompatible packages to be installed and unmet dependencies to arise.

Comment: @Zanna Any way using --force is not recommended ... Question ! Why they put option like this !?!

Comment: Yes I agree with you about that. I think they used `--force` because they read somewhere that they should and didn't realise the meaning

Comment: @Zanna For example you are going to install a package today which need math library and I have to install library by myself . I will tell you install it with --force and I will install library tomorrow !